# Aligning div borders and table borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div and a table side-by-side and align their horizontal borders:

```css
div.table {
  border-radius: .5em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
div.table >:first-child {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}
div.table >:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
div.table table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
}
div.table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  height: 1.4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.table tbody > tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
div.table tbody >:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F9F9F9;
}
div.table tbody >:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
div.table td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: .3em;
}
div.table td,
th {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
div.table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
div.table tr:first-child th {
  border-top: 0px;
}
div.table td:last-child,
div.table th:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
div.table td:first-child,
div.table th:first-child {
  border-left: 0px;
}
div.table div div {
  height: 1.4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0 .2em;
}
div.table div div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Lorem</div>
    <div>Ipsum</div>
    <div>Dolor</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="24"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2x6me2tL/1/

The problem is, in Chrome and IE11, the borders are misaligned by 1px
[image]
while on FF they are perfectly aligned
[image]

Is there a general fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all border styles. then add next:

```
div.table{
    ...
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
div.table td,th{
    ...
    border-left:1px solid silver;
}
div.table td, div.table tr:not(:first-child) th, div.table div div:not(:first-child){
    border-top:1px solid silver;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2x6me2tL/2/